# Eclipse BIRT report multiple pages issue

Tags: eclipse, birt, maximo

I've created a BIRT report to be used by Maximo and when I preview my results I get several pages (one for each record). However when I run the report from Maximo using the same where clause it only generates one of the pages. I did another similar report and it's working. Does anyone have an idea why it's not working for one?

Comment: please list BIRT version, Maximo version, the actual where clause used in preview, application in Maximo, the filter settings in that application. My first guess is that the user doesn't have the rights to view all reports returned by the preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the problem. In the table the dataset was bound to I didn't have any grouping. Once the grouping was added the multiple pages were displaying on both Maximo and BIRT designer preview.